# A relation between quadratic Weyl tensors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

When I deal with the variation of Lagrangian with quadratic Weyl tensors, I met some interesting terms
$$-\frac{1}{4}g_{ef}C^{abcd}C_{abcd}+C_{eabc}C_{f}^{\ \ abc},$$
It is obviously traceless, but is it equal to $0$? I used Maple to calculate the results of some metrics and the answer is $0$. So I try to use the definition of Weyl tensor to prove it and I obtain that it is equal to
$$R_{eabc}R_{f}^{\ \ abc}-\frac{1}{4}g_{ef}R^{abcd}R_{abcd}+2R^{ab}R_{eabf}+g_{ef}R_{ab}R^{ab}-2R_{ea}R_{f}^{a}+RR_{ef}-\frac{1}{4}g_{ef}R^{2}$$
but I can't prove it is $0$. So I wonder if it is a general result.

Comment: if you extremize quadratic Weyl tensor alone, you should get the Bach tensor: $B_{ab}=0$. It is traceless and invariant under conformal rescaling of metric. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bach_tensor

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Actually, I got Bach tensor and above terms, and the equation should be $B_{ab}=0$, so I try to prove the above terms is zero. At first, I thought I was wrong, but the results of Maple give me some confidence. However, I'm not sure about these without proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combination of Weyl tensors vanishes only in $d=4$, and it follows from what is known as the Lanczos identity, which relates the double-dual of any traceless tensor with the symmetries of the Weyl tensor in $d=4$ to the original tensor:
$$
\frac14 \epsilon_{abmn}\epsilon^{cdpq} {C^{mn}}_{pq} = -{C_{ab}}^{cd}
$$
This is discussed, for example, around equation (A.15) and (52) of https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9906087